# Вывод значений в цикле jinja2

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Использую фреймворк *Flask, python, jinja2*. Передаю словарь с тремя списками:

```
attendance = {'total': ['1', ' 5', ' 8', ' 12', ' 15', ' 19', ' 22', ' 26'], 'spravka': ['5'], 'unattended': ['1']}
```

Хочу вывести каждое значение в списке `total` в отдельном теге `li`. Но сделать это не получается. Всегда выводиться значение 1. Цикл не проходит. Что не так?

```
 <ul>
     {% set count = 0 %}
     {% for i in attendance.total %}
     <li>{{ attendance.total[count] }}</li>
     {% set count = count + 1 %}
     {% endfor %}
 </ul>

@app.route('/protected')
@app.route('/visits_s')
def visits_s():
    #........
        attendance = fetch_attendance_data()
        return render_template("visits_s.html", attendance=attendance)
```

Comment: Ваше объявление `attendance` синтаксически неверное, программа просто не запустится.

Comment: Программа запускается. Только выводит всегда значение 1

Comment: Значит в вопрос вы добавили не тот же код, который используется у вас в программе. Запустить с приведённым невозможно.

Comment: А разве total не через скобки должен указываться, это же ключ? `for item in attendance['total']: #some code`

Comment: @kot_mapku3, jinja2 умеет и так, и так.

Answer (score 2):

```
<ul>
  {% for item in attendance.total %}
    <li>{{ item }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```